# Trouble creating signup page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, html5-canvas

right now am trying to make a sign up page for my website currently i have a signup button and some javascript that should be connecting to it so the signup page itself appears

html:

```
 <button class="Sign-Up-Button" id="Sign-Up-Button" onclick="revealSignup"></button>

   <div class="Signing-up" id="Sign-Up">
    <form action="results.html" method="GET">
        <div>
        <label>Name</label>
            <input>
            </div>
        <div>
        <label>Password</label>
             <input>
      </div>
      </form>
      <button id="Sumbit-End">Sumbit</button>
      </div>
```

css:

```
 .Sign-Up-Button{
   background-color: #0099ff;
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: monospace;
   font-size: 25px;
   border-radius: 15px;
   color: white;
   height: 50px;
   width: 105px;
 }
    
    
    .Signing-up {
    position: absolute;
    top: 370px;
    left: 850px;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1; 
        display: none;
    }
```

Java script:

```
function revealSignup(){
    document.getElementById("Sign-Up-Group").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You seem to have forgotten to describe a problem or ask a question.  What isn't working as expected?  Where do you have any element with the id `"Sign-Up-Group"`?  What specifically are you asking?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Forms shouldn't be submitting to other `*.html` pages, generally.  The expectation of a submit is that the data will be processed.  HTML pages cannot process data.  This is, with the caveat that you could GET submit to another page, and with javascript load things on the second page from the query string.  But it's unclear what exactly your submit is expected to do.

Answer (score 0):

First, in Javascript, you need to target #Sign-Up and NOT #Sign-Up-Group because it does not exist in your HTML.
Second, in HTML, you need to open parentheses when you call a function on click

HTML change:

```
<button class="Sign-Up-Button" id="Sign-Up-Button" onclick="revealSignup()"></button>
```

Javascript change:

```
document.getElementById("Sign-Up").style.display = 'block';
```